# Restrict A Row From Being Viewed by A User

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have a Table in MySQL dB but I'm trying to make a particular row (say phone numbers) from being seen by users without certain priviledge. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean column privelege instead of row.
From the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)

**Column Privileges**

Column privileges apply to single columns in a given table. Each privilege to be granted at the column level must be followed by the column or columns, enclosed within parentheses.

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Comment: Yeah! Just so a particular User won't be able to view data on that column in the table.

Comment: When granting permissions on the table, I would grant permissions to all columns except for the 'phone number' column.  'GRANT SELECT (id, name, age, etc...) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';'  I suppose all other users would have desired access.